# are there any Image View transition library for android?

Tags: android, android-animation, slideshow, android-transitions

I need to make transition of imageview which is quite difficult to do by myself. After searching for prebuilt library for hours, I only found some activity transition & simple fade in/out transition.

What I found are material Animation with activities and viewflipper :

https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations
https://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/slide-transition-in-viewflipper/

What I need is vertical bars, dissolve, explode and other advanced transition like in windows movie maker or jquery animation.

[image: Car Dissolve transition]

[image: Car Vertical Bar transition]

If there are any prebuilt android library for this kind of stuff, please let me know. Thanks !

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/6

Comment: @Karan Mer thanks for the link but i didnt find what i needed exactly there

Comment: if you have any idea or link about this than share it in comment !

Comment: @MayurR.Amipara till now i did not find any such transitions, i will be sharing if i found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to write your own custom animations with android animation class. Here is a library link which you can study and modify as need. It contains animation like explode, fold etc.

https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations

For you question, first animation is little difficult. It will need masking for perfect animation like shown above. If you want some easy hint, you can try using two black images like below. Make sure to cover whole screen with black part. Then move one image below and another to right for creating effect.

[image: horizontal bar]

[image: vertical bar]

Second animation is quite simple, you can try something like in hint below:

```
<framelayout>
     <imageview src="@drawable/car.jpg">
     <linearlayout 
         weightsum="9" 
         orientation="horizontal"><!--set it's width height to cover car image-->
        <imageview @+id="imgview1" 
           weight="1" src="@drawable/blackbar.jpg">
        <imageview @+id="imgview2"
           weight="1" src="@drawable/blackbar.jpg">
        .
        .
        <imageview @+id="imgview9"
           weight="1" src="drawable/blackbar.jpg">
     </linearlayout>
</framelayout>
```

In your java code, try following animation for black bars.

```
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setDuration(400);
                    imgBlackBar1.startAnimation(anim);

                }
            });
        }
    }, 150);
```

now, set delay for bar2 300, bar3 450 and so on as you desire.

Comment: for the second animation your solution really worked for me thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

1. Download a set of animation from here:

   ------>     https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_tCPatPrHgyWmNtWjM2X1ZiV1k&ddrp=1#
2. In your android project, if working in Eclipse, open a /res , folder then go to menu:
     file>new>folder>     give name to folder:  "anim".
3. Copy all files to this folder. Just drag them from windows explorer. Now we finished the preparations and ready to use the downloaded.
4. Activity main screen contains one image.  When click happens, image starts to animate, see the code example below:

/*xml file
 *

*end of file
*/

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView image;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {

        image.startAnimation(selectanimation((int)(Math.random()*6))); //randomly select animation 0-5
      }

    });
}
  private Animation selectanimation(int index) {
    switch(index){
    /*
     * create animations, and return them to caller. 
     */
    case 0: return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
    case 1: return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
    case 2: return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left);
    case 3: return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.wave_scale);
    case 4: return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hold);
    case 5: return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_enter);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Download full [source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_tCPatPrHgyS0Z1T19TWUp1WEU/view) Here!

Comment: thanks for your answers i went through all those animations but I could not find what I exactly wanted

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiastic ,  **dilz** also gave sample image for what exactly he wants, he look for like, http://javagraphics.blogspot.in/2007/04/slideshows-transitions-swf.html